# How to set code to automatically delete row from table1 after copying that row to table2

Tags: php, mysql

I set php code to copy specific row from table1 to table2 by html button click. Now I want that specific row to be automatically deleted from table1 as it is copied to table2. On the same php file that copied the row, I want to have a secondary set of codes which should be generated after copy function completes.
Please give me idea regarding how to structure that...

```
/*This files View data from table "rfid_add" & contains php codes and form to INSERT specific row to another table "approved" */
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="view_style.css">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
<title> Request for card  </title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="main">
<center>
<h1> Request for RFID Keyfob </h1>
<table border=1 cellpadding=1 cellspacing=1>
<tr>
<th>SL </th>
<th>Applicant Name </th>
<th>Flat No </th>
<th>Previous Card </th>
<th>Gender </th>
<th>Reason</th>
<th> Auth </th>
<th> Request Date</th>
<th> Action</th>
</tr>

<?php
// Create Connection
    $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

//Select DB
if(!mysqli_select_db($conn, 'lock_access'))
    {   echo "Database not selected"; }
else {
    echo "";}


//Select Query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM rfid_add";

//Execute the SQL query
    $records = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($records))
{
    $idnt  = $row['id'];
    $fln = $row['full_name'];
    $fnum= $row['flat_number'];
    $prid= $row['previous_id'];
    $gndr= $row['gender'];
    $rsn = $row['reason'];
    $atcd= $row['auth_code'];
    $cdate= $row['date'];



// View Table data  
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> $idnt </td>";
    echo "<td> $fln </td>";
    echo "<td> $fnum </td>";
    echo "<td> $prid </td>";
    echo "<td> $gndr </td>";
    echo "<td> $rsn </td>";
    echo "<td> $atcd </td>";
    echo "<td> $cdate </td>";

// These form appears to copy viewed file
    echo "<td> <form action='approve-insert.php' method='POST'>

            <input type='hidden' name='full_name' value='$fln'>
            <input type='hidden' name='flatno' value='$fnum'>
            <input type='hidden' name='gender' value='$gndr'>
            <input type='text' name='pcardno' value=''>
            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Approve'> 


            </form></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
}


?>

</table>
</center>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

```
// These files contains php codes to execute copy to table "approved"
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "lock_access";

$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);

if(!$conn)
{ echo 'Not connected'; 
}
if(!mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname))
{
    echo 'DB Not selected';
}

$fn = $_POST['full_name'];
$fln = $_POST['flatno'];
$gn = $_POST['gender'];
$pcn = $_POST['pcardno'];



$sql = "INSERT INTO approved (full_name, flat_number, gender, new_card) VALUES('$fn', '$fln', '$gn', '$pcn')";


if(!mysqli_query($conn, $sql))
{
    echo "Application not received. ";
}
else {
    echo "<center> 
    <div style='margin-top:400px; margin-bottom:10%'> 
    <p style='color:black; font-size:30px;'> Application from <b> $fn </p> </b> <h2>is </h2>
    <p style='color:green; font-size:40px;'> APPROVED. </p>  
    <p style='color:red; font-size:30px;'>Did you enroll the card? </p>  
    </center> </div>" ;
}

header("refresh:1000; url=view-update.php");
?>
```

Comment: i would suggested researching what SQL injections are, what the security impact is and what you can do about it to prevent it..

Comment: what kind of issues are you facing?

Comment: I just want a row to be DELETed from table1 immediately after it is copied (INSERTed) to table2. None is giving perfect answer. would you please?

Answer (score 0):

If the `id` field is the unique id for the row in the first table, pass that into your `approve-insert.php` file as you do with the other data, and after you have successfully run the insert query, run another query in the same way to delete from the first table where id = the id you passed in.

In fact I'd further change the code so that instead of sending the data that you want to insert, just send the id. Then in `approve-insert`, retrieve the data from the first table, insert it into the second, then delete from the first when you know the insert has worked.

Or if the two tables are otherwise identical, just have an "approved" Boolean column that you set, so there's no copying /deleting of data.

Comment: droopsnoot, Can you please tell me how can I execute another query after first worked? If I set a second query both of them try to be executed at the same time and fails. Tell me how to set it to be executed after 1st one is done.

Comment: I can't see how you could get both queries executing at the same time - can you show the code where that happened? As far as I can see, inside the `else` clause where you display the success message, you should run the second query to delete from the first table.

Comment: Yes it worked buy making another query for DELETE. Thank you